# HowTo: Inform application that database table row is updated?

Tags: windows, multithreading, postgresql, mfc, triggers

I am in process of developing an MFC based Windows based application, using PostgreSQL which would perform

1. Fetches information from the UI
2. Performs some logic and store related information to the database
3. The stored information has to be send immediately OR at schedule interval (ex. at 5:00 on xyz date) over the network

Currently, we have developed a dispacher mechanism (thread ), which constantly polls the database for new information inserted in the database. The thread fetches the information and send to the network module.

But, I feel this is not the correct approach as

1. Polling every time is a overhead. There can be times when there is nothing to execute
2. It is not real time , because we poll after every 5 seconds

So

1. Is there a way to send a trigger to my network module as soon as information is updated in database?
2. Or any better way to achieve this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right @RDX, you shouldnt poll it every time rather you could write a trigger in Postgres and from that trigger try calling a java program which could be seen in the below thread.

[Calling java pgm from Postgres trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614710/postgres-db-trigger-calling-java-function)

Comment: I have put a java program because i know java. Similarly there would be surely a process to call a C# program if your application is on windows.

Comment: And also was wondering that there is one more process of doing it to generate a Notification to the IPC i.e., Inter Process Communication saying that some row got modifield ... Source : [Link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-notify.html)

Comment: can it be called from MFC based application?

Comment: the application is windows MFC dialog based application, ofcourse it uses MVC pattern.

Comment: How? can u share some info

Answer (score 1):

You can use the listen/notify feature of PostgreSQL for this.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html

The clients interested in the messages would execute a `listen` statement and the trigger would then `notify` them.

I don't use C# so, but according to [the manual](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) you can retrieve the messages in an asynchronous manner - which still involves some "lightweight" polling as the notification message is only sent as part of the answer of the server. The manual claims that running an "empty" statement (such as `;`) will be enough. Using Java/JDBC I used a simple `select 42` which doesn't impose a big workload on the server as no tables are touched.

This polling is defintely faster and more scalable than actually retrieving the table's data.